# I have to click the update button twice and the first time all values in the cells of the Gridview disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview set up and populated by binding my data.  I have created a column that holds an "Edit" button.  Clicking that button changes all of my fields to a text box populated with the data that is pulled from the database and replaces the "Edit" button with an "Update" and "Cancel" button.  Up to this point all is working as intended.  I change the value in the textboxes that I want to update and click the "Update" button.  At this point everything is cleared out of all of the text boxes in each cell.  I can enter the data again at this point and click the "Update" button a second time and any values that I have entered (the second time) will be passed back to my updating event procedure, but that is not quite the functionality I'm looking for.

I have run across a couple reports of the "Edit" button requiring 2 clicks to function, but the fixes didn't really apply to my situation.

This is my page_load

```
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                Build_DDL();
                Build_Turn_Checkbox_List();
                Show_Data();
            }            
            CheckBox_Selected_Values();
        }
```

This is my gridview declaration:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerClass" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"
       RowStyle-Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" OnDataBound ="OnDataBound" AllowSorting="True" HeaderStyle-Height="50px"
       OnSorting="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="reportData" OnRowDataBound="GridView_OnRowDataBound"
       OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
       <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" Wrap="True" Height="50px" />
       <RowStyle Wrap="True" CssClass="oddRow" />
       <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="evenRow" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID ="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" Visible="false">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl_state" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("STATE") %>'></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
               <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_state" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("STATE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
               </EditItemTemplate>
```

There are more fields, but they are all built exactly the same.

Here is my update code:

```
        {
            //declare variables
            string stateVal;           

            //set up textboxes
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            TextBox txt_State = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_state");
            stateVal = txt_State.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that when I clicked the "Edit" button on row 2, it was row 5 that was transitioning into text boxes.  This was because I have the following code creating groupings in the gridview and each group creates a new row that is not accounted for in the row index scheme:

```
            helper.RegisterGroup("State", true, true);
            helper.RegisterGroup("Project Type", true, true);
            helper.GroupHeader += new GroupEvent(Helper_GroupHeader);
            helper.ApplyGroupSort();
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I will have to somehow account for the group headers and adjust the neweditindex accordingly.